# How to compare two 2d arrays and get the percentage of compared value in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison, percentage

I'm using latest version of python which is 3.8 and I have two 2d arrays with some data, I want to compare them with each other and wants to get the percentage of similar values.

e:g

arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
arr2 = [1,33,4,56,2,55,4,56,66,5]

as you can see 1,2,4,5 is similar in both arrays. So the percentage will be 40% and Percentage can be in decimal like 40.0% .

I'm beginner ,please tell me the simple and most efficient way to do this. I have very little bit knowledge of numpy as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each of the two lists into sets and then find the len() of the intersection of the two new sets and divide it by the size of the lists (assuming the lists are both of equal length)

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
arr2 = [1,33,4,56,2,55,4,56,66,5]

set_1 = set(arr1)
set_2 = set(arr2)

print(set_1)
print(set_2)

similarity = len(set_1.intersection(set_2)) / len(set_1) * 100
print(f'The similarity is: {similarity}%')
```

You will get 40%

Comment: Yeah but i don't get one thing here that where you're comparing arr1 and 2.

Comment: I am doing a "set intersection". This is a mathematical operation which checks to see which elements the two sets have in common with each other. Refer to [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection) article to highlight set intersection better.